# Syntax question: Desmos graphing calculator and commas. Desmos doesn't like them and gives an error.

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, math-software

My $10$-year-old is playing around with the Desmos graphing calculator, we're trying to input the following to create a spiral, ([we found it on wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#/media/File:Asymptote02_vectorial.svg)):

$$x = t + \frac{\cos(nt)}{t},\quad y = t + \frac{\sin(nt)}{t},\quad t > 0,\quad n = 14.$$

Desmos does not like the commas. How do we do this in Desmos? I'm assuming it's a simple syntax issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desmos will see $(x(t),y(t))$ as a parametric function. The Desmos input should be
$$\left(t+\frac{\cos nt}t,t+\frac{\sin nt}t\right)$$
and then an extra line appears in which the limits of $t$ may be specified. The lower limit is $0$ and the upper limit is whatever is convenient.

(In a separate cell, $n=14$ should be defined first.)

Comment: Thanks this helps, we're beginning to get a spiral. However Desmos doesn't like the 2nd comma before t > 0 .  How do we put in that lower limit?

Comment: @AgentZebra What I put up there should be all alone. _Then_ you will notice something like $0\le t\le 1$ beneath that automatically appears; enter the limits on $t$ there.

Comment: Thanks, we'll retry that. We're loving your art on deviantart.com btw :D. Nice work!